# Uniquness validation on has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a model `AnimalType` which `has_and_belongs_to_many :trainers, join_table: 'trainers_animal_types'` and I need a validation rule so that I can create a Trainer only with existing Animal Types to avoid having a Trainer to have duplicated Animal Typpes. For example, a Trainer can have Animal Types `['Cat', 'Dog']`, not `['Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog']`

```
class AnimalType < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trainers, join_table: 'trainers_animal_types'
end
```

`AnimalType` has only a name in DB.

```
create_table "animal_types", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Join table

```
create_table "trainers_animal_types", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "trainer_id"
  t.integer "animal_type_id"
end
```

Is there a way to validate uniqueness of a name in `has_and_belongs_to_many` association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want uniqueness for `name` field in `animal_types` table right? if yes then

you can add index unique in the table like

`rails generate migration add_index_to_animal_types`

```
# migration file
add_index :animal_types, :name, :unique => true
```

then in the `animal.rb`

`validates :name, uniqueness: true`

and if you want to validates the uniqueness in belongs and has to many tables you can add the unique index like

`rails generate migration add_index_to_trainer_animal_types`

```
# migration file
add_index :trainer_animal_types, [:trainer_id, :animal_type_id], :unique => true
add_index :trainer_animal_types, :trainer_id
add_index :trainer_animal_types, :animal_type_id
```

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid situation where a trainer has duplicated animal types, like `trainer.animal_types #=> ['Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog']`. I want only `['Cat', 'Dog']` There should be only 3 Animal Types in DB and Trainers should be created only with these animal types. I want to avoid duplicated `trainer.animal_types`

Comment: I think you would validate the uniqueness of the Animal Name both in DB and a model, which is not necessary, I think @buncis Am I right?

Comment: everything is necessary I think, because you need to make sure if the 'dog' is the correct 'dog' so you need to made sure the uniqueness in the model and the `has_and_belongs_to_many` table